# Accessing Stratoes dataservice server form application

Tags: jsp, wso2, application-server

I have deployed karshamarkup.war file on Stratoes Application server. I have created  a database on Data services server.  These are my connection details on Data services server.

> Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver JDBC URL:
>   jdbc:mysql://rss1.stratoslive.wso2.com/karshamarkuptool_karsha_opensource_lk
>   Username: root_lQrhzZUK Password: nbuser

This is my connection code on ControllerServelet.java file

```
String connectionURL =    "jdbc:mysql://rss1.stratoslive.wso2.com/karshamarkuptool_karsha_opensource_lk";
Connection connection=null;
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root_lQrhzZUK",
"nbuser");``
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT FIBOTerm from fiboterm");
```

I have inclued the mysql Connector jar in the lib folder  /WEB-INF/lib. 
But I’m unable to pull out data from the Data services server database.  (This works file with my local mysql databse)
Do I need more configurations on Data services server/ app serevr  or on web.xml file to work this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using dataSource = new BasicDataSource() solved my problem, here is how I connected to database

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://rss1.stratoslive.wso2.com/karshamarkuptool_karsha_opensource_lk";
String username = "root2_lQrhzZUK";
 String password = "nbuser";


        dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);



public Connection getConnection()
{
    try
    {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not place the MySQL JDBC driver into your webapp because the StratosLive AppServer already contains it.

Have you created the relevant tables in RSS? Are you getting any error? Please check the logs.